# jQuery: Add 4 weeks to date in format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a string which has a date in the format: dd-mm-yyyy

How I can add 4 weeks to the string and then generate a new string using jQuery / Javascript?

I have

```
var d = new Date(current_date); 
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1); 
current_date_new = (d.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + d.getDate() + '-' + d.getFullYear();    
alert(current_date_new);
```

but it complains that the string provided is in the incorrect format

Comment: http://www.datejs.com/ is a popular shortcut.

Comment: I have 

var d = new Date(current_date);
d.setMonth( d.getMonth( ) + 1 );
current_date_new = ( d.getMonth( ) + 1 ) + '-' + d.getDate( ) + '-' + d.getFullYear( );
alert(current_date_new);

but it complains that the string provided is in the incorrect format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** After a bit of [fiddling](http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/yRrfk/1/), here's the solution:

First, split the string to individual parts.

```
var inputString = "12-2-2005";
var dString = inputString.split('-');
```

Then, parse the string to a datetime object and add 28 days (4 weeks) to it.

```
var dt = new Date(dString[2],dString[1]-1,dString[0]);
dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+28);
```

Finally, you can output the date

```
var finalDate = dt.GetDate() + "-" + (dt.GetMonth()+1) + "-" + dt.GetYear();
```

This code should return `12-3-2005`.

**CAVEATS:** It seems JavaScript's Date object takes 0-11 as the month field, hence the -1 and +1 to the month in the code.

**EDIT2:** To do padding, use this function:

```
function pad(number, length) {

    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }

    return str;

}
```

and change your output to

```
var finalDate = pad(dt.GetDate(),2) + "-" + pad(dt.GetMonth()+1,2) + "-" + dt.GetYear();
```

Check the updated fiddle.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm getting the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object Thu Jun 07 2012 15:20:52 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) has no method 'parse'

Comment: sorry, i just fixed the code...the `var dt` line was wrong.  Try again

Comment: thanks, now it's saying not defined:

Uncaught ReferenceError: parse is not defined

Comment: @saluce months start at `0` (january) not at `1` (february) ;)

Comment: You my friend are a star! all working. One last thing is there any way I can also make sure the months/day are a 2 diggit number?

i.e. instead of 8, how about 08?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert to mm-dd-yyyy, simple split string by the minus sign and create new Date object with the following code:

```
var string = '12-02-2012';
var split = string.split('-');
var date = Date(split[2],parseInt(split[1])-1,parseInt(split[0])+1)

date.setDate(date.getDate() + 28);
var fourWeeksLater = date.getDay() + "-"+date.getMonth() +"-"+date.getYear();
```

Comment: @Zefiryn months start at `0` (january) not at `1` (february) ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should be working:

```
var formattedDate = '01-01-2012',
    dateTokens = formattedDate.split('-'),
    dt = new Date(dateTokens[2], parseInt( dateTokens[1], 10 ) - 1, dateTokens[0]), // months are 0 based, so need to add 1
    inFourWeeks = new Date( dt.getTime() + 28 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 );
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uKDJP/

**Edit:**

Using [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) you can format inFourWeeks:

```
Globalize.format( inFourWeeks, 'dd-MM-yyyy' ) // outputs 29-01-2012
```

Comment: thank you, that does work, but can you make it return the string in the same format of dd-mm-yyyy. At the minute it is the full date/time

Comment: @user1442404: you should use Globalize (https://github.com/jquery/globalize) or similar. I will edit with an example using that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own parser for dates, I would use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

To [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) your date:

```
var date = moment('14-06-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

To [add](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) 4 weeks to it:

```
date.add('weeks', 4);
```

Or in one go:

```
var date = moment('14-06-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY').add('weeks', 4);
```

And [convert](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) it to string:

```
var dateString = date.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```